# Converting richtextbox format to HTML format

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

could anybody give me a resolution to convert the richtextbox format to HTML format, currently I am receiving

`"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><title>Untitled</title><style type=\"text/css\">\r\n.s_D8D99854 { font-family: 'Verdana';font-style: Normal; } \r\n</style></head><body><p ><span class=\"s_D8D99854\">&nbsp;hello</span></p></body></html>"`

from server, where I needed only "**hello**" removing all the tags, so that I can store it further

using MVC, Kendo UI, and getting above formatted code in controller, any help is appreciated

**this format is what I am getting**

[image]

**This format is what I need**

[image]

Comment: can you copy the full code ?

Comment: Hi Syed,   Which code do you need ?? is the code from richtextbox ?? then it so huge it fill upto 3 pages, that's why i posted an image